# App Crashes When Scrolling In UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that is loaded with images from the documents directory. On the simulator (iPhone 6s plus) I don't seem to face any problem but on an iPhone 5 device, when the number of images increase and I have to scroll, the app simply crashes. Here is my code:

In cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier,
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

if directoryUrls.count > 0
{
    var image = UIImage (named: "pending.png")

    let ImgPath = self.documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(String(NSLocalizedString("attachments_folder", comment: "")))/\(self.Attachments[indexPath.row].Name)")

    var mimeType = ""

    if (self.fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(ImgPath.path!))
    {
        mimeType = mimeTypeForPath(ImgPath.path!)
    }
    if (!mimeType.isEmpty)
    {
        if(mimeType.containsString("image"))
        {
            Nuke.taskWithURL(ImgPath)
                {
                    self.MimArray.append("image")
                    self.ImageAttachmentsOnly[self.i] = self.Attachments[indexPath.row]
                    self.i++
                    cell.Image.image = $0.image
                    self.Images.append($0.image!)
                }.resume()
        }
    }
    cell.ImageLabel.text = self.Attachments[indexPath.row].Name
    cell.Image.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

}

return cell
```

The image size in the CollectionViewCell is 70*70 if it is related.

If you would like me to provide more code I will.

This is all what I am getting from the logs:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x38504654> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x38504854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
 Terminating since there is no system app.
```

Comment: i just noticed that the app is crashing and the phone is restarting quickly...

Comment: Are you having memory issues? You can check that out in xCode and Instruments.

Comment: no memory issues. just checked